# NULL Pointer exception trouble

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I'm making a **PigLatin Converter** and I'm having some `NullPointerException`. Now you might ask if I tried on my own to fx it and I my aswer to you is yes I have. Anyways here's my code: **THE line CAUSING THE ERROR WILL END WITH "ERROR"**

```
package project.pkg16.pkg9;

public class Project169_Data {

private static String[] words;
private static String pigLatinWords;

public static void setWords( String input ) {
    words = input.split(" ");
}

public static String convertToPigLatin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String wordTemp = null;
        String word = words[i].toString();
            char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.toString());
            sb.append( String.valueOf(firstLetter).toLowerCase() );
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
            sb.append("ay ");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(wordTemp);   LINE 24 ERROR
            sb2.append(sb.toString());
            pigLatinWords = sb2.toString();
            }
       return pigLatinWords;
    }
}
```

And then here is the 2nd class:

```
package project.pkg16.pkg9;

public class Project169_Main {

public static Project169_Input project169_Input = new Project169_Input();
public static Project169_Data project169_Data = new Project169_Data();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userInput = Project169_Input.getInput();

    project169_Data.setWords(userInput);

    String pigLatinString = project169_Data.convertToPigLatin();       LINE 14 ERROR

 }
}
```

And finally class 3:

```
package project.pkg16.pkg9;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Project169_Input {

public static String getInput() {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("English to Pig Latin");
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter the english words you wish to convert to Pig Latin.");

return input;
} //End of method...
} //End of Class...
```

The error is:

run:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:92)
at project.pkg16.pkg9.Project169_Data.convertToPigLatin(Project169_Data.java:24)
at project.pkg16.pkg9.Project169_Main.main(Project169_Main.java:14)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 31 seconds)
```

Comment: To solve a NPE, you must always first look at the line that throws it as it will give an indication of which variable is null. So which line in your code above throws the NPE?

Comment: Seriously, not even going to tell us where the NPE occurs? Good luck!

Comment: Re: "Now you might ask if I tried on my own to fx it and I my aswer to you is yes I have": I don't think we'd ask *whether* you tried, the question is *what* you tried. And anyway, it's silly to tell us that you got a null pointer exception, but then to give us absolutely no information about it.

Comment: We need a stack trace, and comment the line that throws the exception in the provided code.

Comment: You still need to tell us which line throws the NPE. What is line 24 of your Project169_Data class?

Comment: @John3136 Edited with Error info. Forget sorry.

Comment: In your Project169_Data... `String wordTemp = null;` is better with `String wordTemp = "";`

Comment: @BjørnBråthen: Better not to use wordTemp at all. Just get rid of it and initialize the StringBuilder with its default constructor.

Comment: Yes, couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wordTemp is null and never changed. You're trying to create a StringBuilder with a null variable.

Solution: don't do this.

As an aside: next time, please indicate by comment which line is throwing the NPE. You've yet to do this *still* even after your edit. Please don't force us count each line of your code one at a time. Something like:

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(wordTemp);  // **** this line throws NPE
sb2.append(sb.toString());
pigLatinWords = sb2.toString();
```

Also,

- You'll want to fix your code formatting, especially the indentation which is currently faulty making it hard for you and us to debug.
- I think that you really want to create your StringBuilder with no parameter, and *before* the for loop.
- I think that you want to call `toString()` on the StringBuilder *after* the for loop.